# Erro com publicidade

Tags: android

Estou tentando colocar a publicidade na minha aplicação, minha aplicação tem duas telas a primeira tela eu consegui colocar assim

telainicial.xml

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_unit_id"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

telainicial.java

```
AdView mAdView =  ( AdView ) findViewById ( R . id . adView );
        AdRequest adRequest =  new  AdRequest . Builder (). build ();
        mAdView . loadAd ( adRequest );
```

Assim funciona na primeira tela eu copiei e colei na segunda tela o mesmo codigo e só está ficando o espaço da publicidade

xml completo

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/praias"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/adView" />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_unit_id"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Está aparecendo tudo, mais aonde deveria estar a publicidade esta ficando um buraco branco

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Ilgner poderia incluir o xml da sua segunda tela? Quando você diz, "só está ficando o espaço da publicidade", significa que as outras views não aparecem?

Comment: modifiquei la ta bom

Comment: Nesse layout, a publicidade não aparece? Ou ela aparece e o ListView não? Eu recomendaria usar um `LinearLayout` porque ficaria muito mais simples configurar a altura do `ListView` e do `AdView`. Se for usar um LinearLayout, é só usar o `height="0dp"` e `layout_weight="1"` no `ListView`, o `AdView` permanece igual.

Comment: mais o listview está aparecendo normal , e a publicidade que não aparece , ela não carrega o espaço dela está la normal

Comment: coloquei uma imagem